# Positioning UIWindow in UIScreen in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I need to add additional `UIWindow` to my App. This `UIWindow` should always be positioned in the bottom right corner of the screen despite device's orientation, here's the sketch:
[image]

I've tried to subclass UIWindow like this to be able to set the size and the margins of window:

```
@interface MyWindow : UIWindow

@property (nonatomic) CGSize size;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat margin;

@end

@implementation MyWindow

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size andMargin:(CGFloat)margin {
    self.size = size;
    self.margin = margin;
    return [self initWithFrame:[self calculateFrame]];
}

- (CGRect)calculateFrame {
    return CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-self.size.width-self.margin, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-self.size.height-self.margin, self.size.width, self.size.height);
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self assignObservers];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)assignObservers {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(statusBarDidChangeFrame:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)statusBarDidChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self setFrame:[self calculateFrame]];
}

@end
```

Everything is great on startup! No matter what orientation is on initial start new `UIWindow` position is correct. But when I rotate device - my window goes crazy, it jumps to unexpected positions and I can't figure out why.

Please help!

Comment: Anyone? Please, I really need help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works fine if:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self setFrame:[self calculateFrame]];
});
```

So full working code looks like this:

```
@interface MyWindow : UIWindow

@property (nonatomic) CGSize size;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat margin;

@end

@implementation MyWindow

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size andMargin:(CGFloat)margin {
    self.size = size;
    self.margin = margin;
    return [self initWithFrame:[self calculateFrame]];
}

- (CGRect)calculateFrame {
    return CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-self.size.width-self.margin, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-self.size.height-self.margin, self.size.width, self.size.height);
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self assignObservers];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)assignObservers {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(statusBarDidChangeFrame:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)statusBarDidChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)notification {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self setFrame:[self calculateFrame]];
    });
}

@end
```

Many thanks to Cocoa-Chat and max.lunin :)